# Stoke's Drag Constant

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, drag, viscosity, navier-stokes

I'm trying to calculate Stoke's drag constant using the equation found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_%28physics%29#Very_low_Reynolds_numbers_.E2.80.94_Stokes.27_drag).

The system I wish to calculate it for is a mass oscillating vertically on a spring through air. The temperature is 25 degrees celsius. The area of the base of the mass is $4.9 \times 10^{-4}$ square metres.

I'm not sure how to find the 'fluid viscosity' in the linked equation, or what 'Stoke's radius' is.

Comment: From where, MathsStudent, do You get the idea, that Stokes law is appropriate to Your "spring"? Did You check Reynolds Number?